# Aumentar altura da div com animação usando CSS

Tags: css

Tenho este código que cria uma taça de vinho com CSS:

```css
body{
   background: #000;  
}
.wrap {
  width: 100px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.glass{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
}

.liquid{
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 96px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 100px 100px;
  display:block;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
}

.stem {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 75px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,155.4,178.5) ;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.base {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -6px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <div class="liquid"></div>
  <div class="stem"></div>
  <div class="base"></div>
</div>
```

A parte que simula o líquido na taça é a `div .liquid` que tem altura de `50px`.

Como eu faria para que essa altura fosse de 50px a 100px, de forma animada e que levasse 4 segundos, assim que a página for aberta, usando apenas CSS?

Tentei fazer com o `.animate` do jQuery mas fica travando por causa de outras funções rodando ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Já tentou com `animation` ou `transition` (CSS) ou `requestAnimationFrame` (JS — sugestão devido a tentativa com *jQuery*)?

Comment: Consegui com animation. Vlw!

Comment: Coloca uma resposta com a solução

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Se vc tiver uma resposta, posta aí pra gente.

Comment: Não tenho, mas fiquei curioso de como ficou :)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam resposta postada! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas uma ideia a partir que já fizeram, que claro, pode ser melhorada:

```css
body{
   background: #000;  
}
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.glass{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
}

.liquidcontainner{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 100px 100px;
  bottom: 96px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;
  z-index: -1;
}

.derramar {
  left: 60%;
  border-radius: 0 50px 0 50px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
  animation-name: derramar;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: skewY(-50deg);
}

.liquid{
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
  animation-name: liq;
  animation-duration: 4s; /* 4 segundos */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* faz parar no final */
}

@keyframes liq {
    0% {
      height: 0px;
      transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    25% {
      height: 15px;
      transform: rotate(5deg); 
    }
    50% {
      height: 30px;
      transform: rotate(-5deg); 
    }
    75% {
      height: 45px;
      transform: rotate(5deg); 
    }
    100% {
      height: 60px;
      transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
}

@keyframes derramar {
    0% {
      height: 100px;
      transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    25% {
      height: 85px;
      transform: rotate(5deg); 
    }
    50% {
      height: 70px;
      transform: rotate(-5deg); 
    }
    75% {
      top: 0px;
      height: 55px;
      transform: rotate(5deg); 
    }
    100% {
      top: 40px;
      height: 0px;
      transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
}
.stem {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 75px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,155.4,178.5) ;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.base {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -6px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <div class="liquidcontainner">
    <div class="derramar"></div>
    <div class="liquid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stem"></div>
  <div class="base"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poha! Ficou massa! Tem como encher até o topo não?

Comment: Já sei como fazer. Valeu!

Comment: Editei adicionando um derramar, só colocar o `height` que quiser

Comment: Ficou legal, mas vou te mostrar como está aparecendo no iPhone. O vinho fica quadrado e saindo da taça.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZmNG.jpg Mas tb meu iPhone é dos antigos, iOS 6

Comment: Que estranho, o `overflow` não tá funcionando, talvez tenha que usar um webkit

Answer (score 2):

Consegui com `animation` (sugerido pelo [@Valdeir Psr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr) nos comentários):

```css
body{
   background: #000;  
}
.wrap {
  width: 100px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.glass{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
}

.liquid{
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 96px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 100px 100px;
  display:block;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
  animation-name: liq;
  animation-duration: 4s; /* 4 segundos */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* faz parar no final */
}

@keyframes liq {
    from {height: 50px;}
    to {height: 100px;}
}

.stem {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 75px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,155.4,178.5) ;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.base {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -6px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,222,255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <div class="liquid"></div>
  <div class="stem"></div>
  <div class="base"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depois fala que não manja de CSS :p

Comment: rsrs... quando envolve animações e outros efeitos eu sou mt fraco.

Comment: Então pelo visto já está se virando bem! []'s

Comment: Isso está errado!! O correto é `from {height: 100px;}
    to {height:50px;}`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo é o contrário rs

Comment: @dvd, então tá, você enche a taça (com um bom vinho) e eu esvazio.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Vou encher com pinga pra vc rs..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA2HV.png

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo maior falta de sacanaji rss